# How to fix overlapping inputs in Bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm having issues with input boxes overlapping each other as the screen starts shrinking down in width. Is there way to fix this in bootstrap 2 files or directly adjusting the css inline?

Here is the main page that holds the content.

```
<div class="content-center">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="content-area">

            //WHERE CONTENT IS LIVING


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="content-area">

                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the actual code where the content is at.

```
<div class="well">
<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="span4">

<h4>Dinner Banquet w Cocktail Reception Total:</h4>

<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on" style="font-size:24px;">$</span><INPUT NAME="xbrunchdinneronlytotal" TYPE="text"  style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; color:#2e713b; background-color:#ffffff;" onKeyUp="javascript:getbrunchdinnertotal(this);" value="0" >
</div>


</div>

<div class="span4">
<h4>Wine Tour:</h4>

<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on" style="font-size:18px;">Qty</span>
<input type="text" name="xwinetouronly"  onKeyUp="javascript:getwinetouronlytotal(this);" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
</div>

<h4>Total:</h4>

<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on" style="font-size:24px;">$</span>
<INPUT NAME="xwinetouronlytotal" TYPE="text" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; color:#2e713b; background-color:#ffffff;" onKeyUp="javascript:getwinetouronlytotal(this);" value="0"></div>

</div>

<div class="span4">

<h4>Exhibit Fee:</h4>
<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on" style="font-size:24px;">$</span>
<INPUT NAME="xhibittotal" TYPE="text" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px; color:#2e713b; background-color:#ffffff;" onKeyUp="javascript:getgolftotal(this);" value="0" >
</div>


</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is the browser width at 1199px

[image]

And here is the browser width at 979px
[image]

So is there any way to fix this. I know I can mess with the media query in my own custom css but im also wondering if I can fix this in the bootstrap 2 source files. Or Just fix this directly with inline CSS

Answer (score 0):

Put all your inputs into columns

`<div col-lg-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-sm-12>
    Dinner Banuqet
   //input field
    </div>
    <div col-lg-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-sm-12>
    Wine Tour
   //input field
    </div>
   <div col-lg-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-sm-12>
   Exhibit Fee
    //input field
    </div>`

on a large and meduim screen there will be 3 columns with the content taking up the whole screen.  On small and extra small screens the content will be vertically aligned.  You can add the cols directly into your input-append class

Comment: Isnt this for bootstrap 3?